# How to not render transclusion slot when it's not provided in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-components

I have an AngularJS component which uses transclusion with 2 transclusion slots. One of them (`messageHeading`) is optional and sometimes will not be provided at all. Code below:

### message.js

```
import template from "./messsage.html";

angular.component('message', {
    transclude: {
        heading: '?messageHeading',
        content: 'messageContent'
    },
    template
});
```

### message.html

```
<aside class="message">
    <h2 class="message__heading"
        ng-transclude="heading"></h2>
    <p class="message__paragraph"
       ng-transclude="content"></p>
</aside>
```

### Question

**How can I not render `<h2>` element at all, when `messageHeading` is not provided?** In the current default behaviour it's rendered, only with empty contents, but I want it to never appear in the DOM.

Using `ngIf` on `<h2>` seems like a natural way to do it, but I don't know how to write a condition which would be true only when the transclusion argument was provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I worked it out myself. There is `$transclude` service, which provides method `isSlotFilled(nameOfTheSlot)` to check if the slot has been filled. You can use that as a value of the `ngIf` condition and so render `<h2>` only when the slot has been filled.

### message.js

```
import template from "./messsage.html";


class MessageController {
    constructor($transclude) {
        this.hasHeading = $transclude.isSlotFilled('heading');
    }
}


angular.component('message', {
    transclude: {
        heading: '?messageHeading',
        content: 'messageContent'
    },
    controller: MessageController,
    template
});
```

### message.html

```
<aside class="message">
    <h2 class="message__heading"
        ng-if="$ctrl.hasHeading"
        ng-transclude="heading"></h2>
    <p class="message__paragraph"
       ng-transclude="content"></p>
</aside>
```